# Proving the translation operator is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling with this one proof in the example of my lecture notes.

Given $\hat{T}_{h} f(x)$ = $f(x+h)$, i.e. translation along the x-axis by an amount h or -h, and h is a real constant, show that $\hat{T}_{h}$ is linear.

I know that an operator is linear if the following property holds: $\hat{A} (c_{1} f_{1} + c_{2} f_{2}) = c_{1} \hat{A} f_{1} + c_{2} \hat{A} f_{2}$. The previous examples I was able to follow along easily because they were just simply multiply by some variable or square the whole term itself and show whether the LHS equals the RHS, but this time, it is directly affecting the argument in the function itself. Anyone know how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)$. Then $$\hat T_hg(x)=g(x+h)=c_1f_1(x+h)+c_2f_2(x+h)=c_1\hat T_hf_1(x)+c_2\hat T_hf_2(x)$$

Comment: Okay thank you! This is what I thought I should do, I just wasn't sure if it was appropriate to cast the constants within g(x) but now that I think about it, this is probably the only way.